# How would one say "Pardon me," in the sense of not understanding or hearing, in Classical Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, idiom, politeness

Especially when speaking a second language, I am forced to frequently say something like "Pardon me?" or "What was that?" or "Excuse me?" when I fail to understand or hear what a speaker says.  I'd like to know what was used in Classical Latin to express one's remorse for not understanding while asking the other speaker to repeat himself.

A [quick search for "pardon"](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/perseus-cgi/search3t?dbname=lewisandshort&dgdivhead=&matchtype=sameold&word=pardon&CONJUNCT=PHRASE) in L&S provides many options, but I can't tell if any of them apply to this situation.  John Traupman offers *ignosce mihi* for "Excuse me," but I'm not sure if that can be used in the situation I'm describing here (as opposed to accidentally inconveniencing or harming someone).

So how do I say "Pardon me" in Classical Latin, to politely apologize for not understanding and imply a desire for the other speaker to repeat himself?

Comment: I find euphemisms don't usually translate well to other languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest to this idiomatic phrase I could find was:

> *quaeso, quid narras?*
>   sorry, what are you saying?

Terence, *Phormio*, act 5, scene 8

Which, in this particular dialogue, is not quite “sorry, I didn’t hear that, could you repeat it?” but more a rhetorical “excuse me, what on earth are you saying?”  However, it does seem that ***quaeso + verb of speaking/repeating/telling*** certainly does encapsulate that casual, almost throwaway “excuse me/pardon/what was that?” that we use in English.

Another similar example is the following:

> *dic dum, quaeso, mi, es tu Myconius?*
>   excuse me, tell me, are you from Myconos?

Terence, *The Mother-in-Law*, act 5, scene 3

This is very different from *ignosce mihi* which is often used more like “pardon me, I’ve done something I really hope you will overlook”.  Here it is used in a casual way like the *quaeso* above, yet the tone/meaning is slightly different:

> *tunc tunc—ignoscite (nolo, quid faciam?) sed sum petulanti splene—cachinno*
>   then, then - excuse me (I don’t want to, what can I do?) but I have a cheeky temper – I cackle

Persius, *Satires*, 1

Or:

> *quisquis es, ignoscas; in nullam lumina partem
>
>   gurgite ab hoc flexi studioque operatus inhaesi*
>   whoever you are, please forgive me; I haven’t taken my eyes off this pool so intent am I on fishing [and therefore can't help you in your search]

Ovid, *Metamorphoses*, 8.864–5

**EDIT:**

Since posting my original answer, I came across the following two examples that you might find useful for your context (speaking a second language).

> Phormia: *cena “dubia” apponitur*
>
> the “problematic” meal is set before you
>
> Geta: *quid istuc verbist?*
>
> what sort of expression is that?

Terence, *Phormio*, act 2, scene 2

> Hanno: whispers something in an aside
>
> Milphio: *quid ais tu?*
>
> what are you saying?

Plautus, *Poenulus*, act 5, scene 2
(This is actually a very funny scene where Hanno, a Carthaginian, speaks Punic and Agorastocles pretends to translate for his master, Milphio)

I don’t think either phrases are particularly polite, but perhaps if you just added a *quaeso*, it would soften it?

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a few options, of varying degrees of politeness. A few are:

*Peto (te) quod dicis iterare* is a bit wordy; *peto ut hoc iterares* is neater.

*Veniam abs te peto, sed sermonem non cepi* would be very polite.

*Quid dixisti?* is rather abrupt.

Comment: A note on *peto te*: *peto* "ask" with accusative is marked as "ante- and post-classical" in Lewis and Short; standard classical usage would be *peto a(bs) te*, and with an *ut* clause rather than an infinitive, as in your second example. A more colloquial phrasing might be something like *Itera, amabo te*.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you have sources for these showing their use in Classical Latin?

Comment: @Nathaniel You can easily find them in any comprehensive lexicon. I prefer Smith's which, though 140 years old, is very reliable

Comment: @TKR I wouldn't argue with your comments, but are we looking for standard classical usage? We shouldn't expect too much precision and formality in a (necessarily) spoken question, but should tailor it to the context.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I don't really even know where to begin looking there.  Including links to the relevant page numbers would be really helpful.  For example, https://books.google.com/books?id=jeQIAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA536 points to page 536 of Smith's English-Latin dictionary (the page number is indicated in the "PA536" part at the end).

Comment: The desired register/variant is a question for the OP of course, but the question does ask "what was used in Classical Latin".