# Translating "understand" in a conversation

Tags: vocabulary, conversational

What is the best verb to be used in phrases like "I'm sorry, I didn't understand" or "Did you understand?" in Latin?
In English one might use "understand" or "get", in Italian perhaps "capire" is the most common choice.
But how about Latin?
I can see several options, but I don't know what is most natural in conversational Latin: *intelligere, capere, cognoscere, cernere, scire, sentire, videre…*

This is related to [an older question about "Pardon me" when not understanding something](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1830/79).
This question is focused on the quest for suitable verbs for all conversational situations, not a phrase for "pardon me, I didn't understand".

Comment: My old Rosetta Stone Latin course had *te non intellexi; repete, quaeso,* but that *was* Rosetta Stone.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're thinking specifically of those times when you didn't quite catch what someone said but I thought this question might naturally link to a previous question about saying "pardon, I didn't quite hear/understand what you said": https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1830/how-would-one-say-pardon-me-in-the-sense-of-not-understanding-or-hearing-in/4437#4437

Comment: @Penelope I was thinking of a general verb (or several) to be used in all kinds of conversational situations. I faintly remembered we had had something similar, but couldn't quite remember what it was. That question is certainly relevant. Thanks for the reminder and the link!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UPDATE & EDIT: My first answer read as though it was simply trying to establish the use of *intellegere* when what I meant to make clear is that *intellegere* is by far and away the most frequently-used verb for this type of exchange (based mainly on Plautus and Terence).  Next most used is *scire* and I have added new material to that section below.  I have also expanded on casual ways of asking "do you understand?" and added a new verb, *callere*.

---

Looking at casual, conversational exchanges, ***intellegere*** is the most frequently used, particularly in the negative.  For example:

> *[quid est?] non intellego*
>
> what? I don't understand

Plautus, *The Ghost*, 475

> *nam prorsum nil intellego*
>
> I don't understand at all

Terence, *The Self-Tormentor*, 775

> *non hercle intellego*
>
> I don't understand by Hercules

Terence, *The Woman of Andros*, 190

> *sed parum intellego quid me velis scribere*
>
> but I don't quite understand what you want me to write

Cicero, *Letters to Atticus*, 380

> *avunculum meum dixisse:* "*intellexeras nempe?*"
>
> my uncle said, "couldn't you understand him?"

Pliny the Younger, *Letters*, 5.12

***Scire*** is the next most used verb to say "I don't understand".  Here's a great example, with bonus idiom:

> *quin nec caput nec pes sermoni apparet. nec quid dicatis scire nec me
>   quor ludatis possum.*
>
> Neither head nor foot of your speech is clear.  I can't understand what
>   you're saying or what you're playing at.

Plautus, *Comedy of Asses*, 729-730

An interesting use of *scire* is to combine it with *noscere* to emphasise just how much you don't understand:

> *nec vos qui homines sitis novi nec scio*
>
> I neither know nor understand who you guys are

Plautus, *The Braggart Soldier*, 450.  See also Plautus, *Pseudolus*, 1210

A similar combination of verbs, this time *nescire* and ***capere*** (the only use of *capere* I found) occurs in Terence, *The Self-Tormentor*, 955:

> *nescio nec rationem capio*
>
> I don't know or understand the reason

When asking "do you understand?", again *intellegere* and *scire* are both often used (*satin intellegis?*, *iam scis?*, for example).  But  ***tenere*** is also frequently seen in both Plautus and Terence: simply *tenes?* in *Phormio* 210, or *satin haec meministi et tenes?* in Plautus, *The Persian*, 183, are just two examples.

***audistin?*** is attested in Terence, *The Brothers*, to essentially mean "do you understand?"

Lastly, I came across ***[callere](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=callere&la=la#lexicon)*** being used to mean "to understand", which was new to me and so I add it here.  Examples: *callemus probe* / we understand well (Plautus, *The Little Carthaginian*, 575) and *docte calleo* (Plautus, *The Persian*, 380).

Answer (score 5):

To say *non intelligo* always seems a bit heavy-handed and instead I think you can pretty much make up this sort of informal adjunct to conversation, much as we do in English. *Capio* is useful here: *Veniam da, sed hoc non cepi*  is acceptable as 'excuse me, but I didn't understand', or 'I didn't catch that'. You can also use *non carpsi* in the exact sense of 'I didn't quite gather what you said'.

I can't place specific instances from memory, but this sort of thing is most likely to occur during conversation found in plays. I should think that Plautus in particular has some good examples.