# Acknowledging Message, e.g. "Copy that" or "Roger"

Tags: vocabulary, word-request, contemporary-latin

In English there are certain phrases, like "copy that" or "roger" that are used to confirm that a message was received, especially in radio communication.  What would be a good Latin term or phrase to use in this case?  My thought was `intelligetur`, but I'm curious if there is a better term to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with *intellego* (or the alternative spelling *intelligo*).
For example, it appears in Plautus, *Epidicus* [249](http://latin.packhum.org/loc/119/9/3/4249-4258,6150-6159,6362-6372@1#3) and [278](http://latin.packhum.org/loc/119/9/3/4249-4258,6150-6159,6362-6372@2#3).
For other examples, mainly negative, see [this question about "understand" or "get" in a conversation](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5069/79).

I would prefer active voice here; after all, the message is that I understand, not that the thing is understood in general.
If you use passive, present tense (*intelligitur/intellegitur*) is better than future (*intelligetur/intellegetur*).
Another option that comes to mind but for which I found no classical attestations is the perfect tense version *intellexi*.
My best suggestion is the simplest one: present, indicative, and active ***intellego***.